# How can I send two requests simultaneously by html code?

Tags: html, testing, web-applications, race-condition

I have a user registration form that a user can complete its fields ( user name, password , email ) to register his account. I want to change this form, when a user click submit button, it seems like that it clicks the button twice. in other words, I want to send two  identical simultaneous requests to the server. how can I do this ?
my html code is like this:

in fact I want to implement race condition issue. as you know in any user registration form the username must be unique. I want to test the web application that it can be get into the race condition and store two identical username or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="register">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form action="register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            
                <label for="username">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
                <label for="password">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
                <label for="email">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Register">
                                
            
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about create a new form and redirect to that form after Registration? This will solve your issue.

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. _Why_ do you need two identical requests? This would be a highly unusual thing to do, not only that you could just process things twice on your server instead of requiring the client to send two requests, but it sounds very weird to execute the same user registration twice in the first place (regardless of where the duplication is implemented). What purpose does that serve?

Comment: in fact I want to implement race condition issue. as you know in any user  registration form the username must be unique. I want to test the web application that it can be get into the race condition and store two identical username or not?

Comment: Oh, so this is part of quality assurance or a (self-)penetration test? Please revise your question and include this important piece of information. Thank you.

Comment: I edit my question, Thanks a lot for your advice

Comment: @noobprogrammer thanks but it does not solve my issue

Comment: I'm not sure the mechanism you are building will actually validate your application for name unicity. It is too dependant on other factors, like network.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a solution without some javascript for doubling the submit.

An other way would be to post the requests from a batch (curl) or a tool (JMeter, Postman, ...)